# Slack API Interconnectivity & Shortcuts Error with Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, slack-api

I set up an azure function with an anonymous auth level to respond to the Interconnectivity and Shortcuts with the slack API. I was doing some reading and it appears that the URL has to end with /events/slack in order to respond. My function url is

```
https://<namehere>.azurewebsites.net/api/events/slack?
```

The basic idea is that I have a home page on my bot which has 1 button. When clicking that button I want to do literally anything just so I can test that it works.

When I click the button it displays a 500 server error.

Looking at the logs for my function this is the exact error

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: p. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

This is the basic code for the function

```
[FunctionName("abc123")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "events/slack")] HttpRequest req,
ILogger log)
{
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

    return new OkObjectResult("cool");
}
```

As far as my understanding goes, I set everything up correctly. Doesn't this error indicate there is something wrong with the JSON being sent and not an error with parsing? Is it just not possible to use an azure function as the end point for Slack's Interconnectivity & Shortcuts?

I am confused on what I am doing wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I stupidly didn't read how Slack sends the request and they use a form encoded url for interactivity. The solution here is to just parse out payload= via the following code

```
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
string payloadData = requestBody.Replace("payload=", "");
string decodedPayload = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(payloadData);
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(decodedPayload);
```